# Failed to build iOS app. Error output from Xcode build (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, ios-simulator, emulation

I had to update the main activity.java file in the android folder for a flutter project, and update it to V2, but I could not find it. So, I made it from scratch. When I did all that, I suddenly got an error when trying to run the app on the iOS and android emulators. I deleted the whole sdk, android studio and Xcode, but still the same problem. See code below.

What do I do?

Thx

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            5.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/yl/zgnwjxdn5jlcqg8dby0bysj40000gn/T/flutter_tools.SDJ8Qi/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir3vqkEZ/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    Improperly formatted define flag:  Android
    Failed to package /Users/user/1.Developer/Projects/The Complete Flutter UI Masterclass | iOS, Android, & Web/test_project.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/yl/zgnwjxdn5jlcqg8dby0bysj40000gn/T/flutter_tools.SDJ8Qi/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir3vqkEZ/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your project is in a folder that contains special characters `,`, `&` and `|`. Especially the `,` is causing errors here.

```
The Complete Flutter UI Masterclass | iOS, Android, & Web
```

Simplify the folder name, clean your project and try again